# python: os.system does not execute shell comand

Tags: python

I need to execute shell command in python program (I have ubuntu). More specifically I want to create graph using graphviz in python script. My code is

```
os.system("dot -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png")
```

It does not work, but if I just type `dot -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png` in command line then everything is fine. Do you know what the problem? Thank you!

**Edit:** *Does not work* means that nothing happens, there are no errors.

Output from  `dot -v -Tpng graph.dot -o graph.png`:

```
dot - graphviz version 2.26.3 (20100126.1600)
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_pango.so.6
Using textlayout: textlayout:cairo
Activated plugin library: libgvplugin_dot_layout.so.6
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Using render: cairo:cairo
Using device: png:cairo:cairo
The plugin configuration file:
    /usr/lib/graphviz/config6
        was successfully loaded.
    render  :  cairo dot fig gd map ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
    layout  :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device  :  canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot eps fig gd gd2 gif gv imap         imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg pdf plain plain-ext png ps ps2 svg svgz tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp x11 xdot xlib
    loadimage   :  (lib) eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
```

Comment: For future coding related questions, post to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). +1 for Python :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I should close file graph.dot before executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, I just tried with the same command and it gave me the expected output (that graph.dot doesn't exist)
Are you sure you have

```
import os
```

?
Also, are you sure that this piece of code that executes the 'dot' command isn't in a untrue condition (in an 'if' statement that is untrue, so the piece of code after this never executes)?